# How can I change or remove HTML form validation default error messages?

Tags: html, validation

For example I have a `textfield`. The field is mandatory, only numbers are required and length of value must be 10. When I try to submit form with value which length is 5, the default error message appears: `Please match the requested format`

```
<input type="text" required="" pattern="[0-9]{10}" value="">
```

1. How can I change HTML form validation errors default messages?
2. If the 1st point can be done, is there a way to create some property files and set in that files custom error messages?

Comment: I found a bug on Mahoor13 answer, it's not working in loop so I've fixed it & give answer with some correction, which you can find under the answer section.

**Here is the link**
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361460/how-can-i-change-or-remove-html5-form-validation-default-error-messages/42430173#42430173

Answer (score 250, accepted):

This is the JavaScript solution:

```
 <input type="text"
    pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"
    oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter Alphabets.')"
    onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" />
```

The "onchange" event needs when you set an invalid input data, then correct the input and send the form again.
I've tested it on Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

**But for Modern Browsers:**

Modern browsers didn't need any JavaScript for validation.
Just do it like this:

```
<input type="text"
    pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"
    title="Please enter Alphabets."
    required="" />
```

Comment: I suggest against using inline events. It's not a good practise.

Comment: @Mahoor13 I have written it similar to that, but it never validates. Can you gimme a hint ? http://jsfiddle.net/2USxy/

Comment: There's also a custom Firefox property you can add which works well: x-moz-errormessage="Please enter only numbers"

Comment: better to use "onkeyup" instead of "onchange" to see effectively if the input is valid or not.

Comment: replacing oninput with onchange fixed my problem on firefox when textFiled is focused

Comment: On Chrome 52, oninvalid fired BEFORE onkeyup, so I ended up without the custom message. I successfully used onkeypress instead.

Comment: This has the following problem (at least in Chrome 55) : when the invalid message pops , if the user keeps focus  in the invalid field (without clicking) and edits the field the message keeps poping out - even when the field is valid - it's necessary to either focus out or trigger submit.

Answer (score 112):

When using pattern= it will display whatever you put in the title attrib, so no JS required just do:

```
<input type="text" required="" pattern="[0-9]{10}" value="" title="This is an error message" />
```

Comment: Nice answer, but be careful about backward (or even current) compatibility here.

Comment: When I set a title to "foo" I get "Please match the requested format. foo", so this won't work for me

Comment: Title is also used as the tooltip text on mouse hover, so I would stay away from this approach.

Comment: Title is also used as the tooltip text on mouse hover, so this is probably the best approach.

Comment: I think the idea with the `title` attribute is to describe the requirement like "Enter a 10-digit number." rather than an error like "This is not a valid number". When describing the requirement, there is no problem with the same text appearing both in mouse hover and in the validation error message. (I'm not saying my wording is the best, I know it could be argued whether or not to say "Enter..." vs. "Value must be..." etc.)

Comment: this will most assuredly fail a11y

Answer (score 37):

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"
oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Plz enter on Alphabets ')" />
```

I found this code in another post.

Comment: thanks, it worked for me. Though I did not find post or blog or site mentioning this.

Comment: Take note on the following post when considering using setCustomValitidy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867407/html5-why-does-my-oninvalid-attribute-let-the-pattern-fail

Answer (score 17):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{10}" oninvalid="InvalidMsg(this);" name="email" oninput="InvalidMsg(this);"  />
```

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
function InvalidMsg(textbox) {

     if(textbox.validity.patternMismatch){
        textbox.setCustomValidity('please enter 10 numeric value.');
    }    
    else {
        textbox.setCustomValidity('');
    }
    return true;
}
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/patelriki13/Sqq8e/5)</kbd>

Answer (score 15):

To prevent the browser validation message from appearing in your document, with jQuery:

```
$('input, select, textarea').on("invalid", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 13):

you can remove this alert by doing following:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"
    oninvalid="setCustomValidity(' ')"
/>
```

just set the custom message to one blank space

Answer (score 11):

you can change them via constraint validation api: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/constraints.html#dom-cva-setcustomvalidity

if you want an easy solution, you can rock out civem.js, Custom Input Validation Error Messages JavaScript lib
download here: https://github.com/javanto/civem.js
live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/hleinone/njSbH/

Answer (score 6):

I Found a way Accidentally Now:
you can need use this: data-error:""

```
<input type="username" class="form-control" name="username" value=""
placeholder="the least 4 character"
data-minlength="4" data-minlength-error="the least 4 character"
data-error="This is a custom Errot Text fot patern and fill blank"
max-length="15" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{4,}"
title="4~15 character" required/>
```

Answer (score 5):

The setCustomValidity let you change the default validation message.Here is a simple exmaple of how to use it.

```
var age  =  document.getElementById('age');
    age.form.onsubmit = function () {
    age.setCustomValidity("This is not a valid age.");
 };
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a bug on Mahoor13 answer, it's not working in loop so I've fixed it with this correction:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="email" id="eid" name="email_field" oninput="check(this)">
```

**Javascript:**

```
function check(input) {  
    if(input.validity.typeMismatch){  
        input.setCustomValidity("Dude '" + input.value + "' is not a valid email. Enter something nice!!");  
    }  
    else {  
        input.setCustomValidity("");  
    }                 
}
```

It will perfectly running in loop.

Answer (score 4):

This is work for me in Chrome

```html
<input type="text" name="product_title" class="form-control" 
    required placeholder="Product Name" value="" pattern="([A-z0-9À-ž\s]){2,}"
    oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter on Producut Name at least 2 characters long')" />
```

Comment: when I try this, the invalid message appears when the value is invalid, but it doesn't go away when the field becomes valid again - it just stays there forever

Comment: update: I got the same behaviour in Chrome and Safari. I had to set it to '' in onChange, then it worked ok, like in some other answers here.

Answer (score 4):

To set custom error message for HTML validation use,

```
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Your custom message goes here.')"
```

and to remove this message when user enters valid data use,

```
onkeyup="setCustomValidity('')"
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see here:

[html5 oninvalid doesn't work after fixed the input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14834276/5497937)

Is good to you put in that way, for when you fix the error disapear the warning message.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(this.willValidate?'':'your custom message')" />
```