# Symfony2 html5 form multiple validation message possible?

Tags: php, html, symfony, validation

There is the great functionality of using html5 validation in symfony2 forms.

After searching a while in the internet, I found this **great** solution:

- [Overriding Form Validation messages on symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257491/overriding-form-validation-messages-on-symfony2)

But this gives me allways only **one** validation-message

> Would you please enter a valid email?

What about multiple validation-messages? Like it is described in the docs:

- http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/translation.html#book-translation-constraint-messages

So I'm able to use either html5 form-validation with **one** message, or I'm able to use normal validations (like in the link) with multiple messages, but no client-side validation like html5 (Of course, I could implement some validation functions, but I'd prefer to use the built-in html5 functionality)

*Edit: I did some research, It looks like this html5 form-validation has nothing to do with the symfony2 framework, is that correct? So basically without creating too much client-side code, I'm only able to make check for "required" (which is the original reason of this attribute).*

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: I did some research, It looks like this html5 form-validation has nothing to do with the symfony2 framework, is that
>   correct? So basically without creating too much client-side code, I'm
>   only able to make check for "required" (which is the original reason
>   of this attribute).

basically yes , you can add some attributes to your tags when you build your form `builder->add("name","text",array("attr"=>array(" ... "`  , and yes marking marking a field has required had a required attribute to your html tag.
If you want to turn of the html5 validation you can use the novalidate attribute in the form tag , then use a client js library to do the work or whatever.

**A trick i like to use is with js**, on submit , send the form to the server as an ajax request , then get the new html rendered form as a response , so I get the awesomeness of symfony and javascript combined without the need of a js validation library. You just need to write the an on submit handler with some ajax.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. My 5 cent's to your trick: It's okay, but I'm not a fan of these tricks... You'll have a call to your webserver anyway, the advantage of html5 form-validation would have been making less calls to webserver... but it's fancy too.
I think I don't want to use javascript validation at the moment..