# HTML5 pattern to work

Tags: regex, html

I've not been able to make work this html5 form validation. **Anybody please suggest how to fixed it**. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vusan/nZrbq/2/)
When I press any key on the input box the firebug console says `SyntaxError: invalid quantifier`

```
    <form action="#" method="post" class="form-validate" id="bidform">

      <div class="input_wrapper">
         <input placeholder="Enter Zip Code" type="text" pattern="[0-9]{3,5}"
            oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter valid zip')" id="zip" class="validate-numeric" required name="zip">
      </div>


      <div class="submit_row">
         <input class="submit" value="Submit a Bid!" type="submit" name="subbid">
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the pattern is invalid. If you are trying to match 5 digits you just need "[0-9]{5}". If you are trying to match 3-5 digits it should be "[0-9]{3,5}".

There also seems to be an issue with setCustomValidity(). After it gets called once any furter attempts to submit the form always result in error.

[How can I change or remove HTML5 form validation default error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361460/how-can-i-change-html-5-form-validation-errors-default-messages) suggests that you can fix this by adding `onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"`.

Comment: I want to match the digit 3-5

Comment: I check putting {3,5} but It don't work. thanks @Nathan I will update my answer again.

Comment: It's not working too. My problem now is that we can submit with any input character if we just have refreshed. But if we submit with blank, the tooltips appear and then after the tooltips continue to appear ignoring our any pattern.

Comment: I've been having that problem too. It seems to go away when I remove oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter valid zip')"

Comment: But how to make our custom message? Now I'm checking that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361460/how-can-i-change-html-5-form-validation-errors-default-messages seems to suggest that you need to add onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"

Comment: thanks for your help which really solve my problem. Now I am managing my code by just putting alert to just work for now. `oninvalid="if(this.value) alert('invalid zip')"`.

Answer (score 0):

Strange error, I see it in Firefox as you described but it works fine in Opera. Anyway, it seems related to you regular expression somehow so changing that a bit made it work fine there as well. Instead of using `{3}{5}` to tell the number of digits I simply wrote it as `\d\d\d\d?\d?` making three digits required and the two last one optional.

Comment: I just changed the pattern-attribute to `pattern="\d\d\d\d?\d?"`.