# Why does my "oninvalid" attribute let the pattern fail?

Tags: html, input

This little HTML5 password field works perfectly WITHOUT the oninvalid attribute (the pattern say: minimum 6 characters):

```
<form>
    <input type="password" name="user_password_new" pattern=".{6,}" required />      
    <input type="submit"  name="register" value="Register" />
</form>
```

See the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DypgB/).

But when I add an oninvalid attribute that gives out a custom error message when user's input does not fit the pattern, the entire field NEVER becomes valid, see the code here:

```
<form>
    <input type="password" name="user_password_new" pattern=".{6,}" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Minimum length is 6 characters')" required />      
    <input type="submit"  name="register" value="Register" />
</form>
```

See the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2USxy/).

**Can you spot the mistake ?**

Answer (score 119, accepted):

If you set a value with `setCustomValidity()` then the field is invalid.  That is setting a non-zero length string causes the browser to consider the field invalid.  In order to allow for the effects of any other validations you have to clear the custom validity:

```
<input type="password" name="user_password_new" pattern=".{6,}" required
   oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Minimum length is 6 characters')" 
   oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
```

Comment: You Sir, are my hero! Perfect answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A good explanation. A simpler solution to the problem is to remove the `oninvalid` attribute and use the `value` attribute instead to contain a short explanation of the expected data format. This is the way recommended in HTML5 CR. The attribute `value="Minimum length is 6 characters"` would work both as clarifying the error message and as a tooltip on mouseover.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: I think you mean the `title` attribute.

Comment: @TimYates, you’re right. Read both occurrences of `value` in my comment as `title`.

Comment: Note, I thought this wasn't working for radio buttons but it was because I only did it on the first one and it happened to be disabled in this case. It seems, at least in Chrome, the error message is taken from the first enabled radio button. So in order to make sure the custom message is always used it needs to be set on every radio input, unfortunately. Probably better to just do in JS depending on amount of radio buttons.

Answer (score 19):

Since I stumbled on the same problem, here is my solution – tested and working with FF, Chrome, IE 10, Edge (Feb 2017).

```html
<form>
<input pattern="1234" oninput="setCustomValidity(''); checkValidity(); setCustomValidity(validity.valid ? '' :'please enter 1234');">
<input type="email" required>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Explanation:**

`setCustomValidity('');` removes the custom error string which otherwise would always result in an invalid field at the validation process.

`checkValidity();` does a manual validation – the same as it is happening at the form submisson. The result is stored in `validity.valid`.

The second `setCustomValidity(validity.valid ? '' :'please enter 1234');` now sets the error string according to the validation result. If the field is valid it needs to be empty, otherwise the custom error string can be set.

Comment: This does fit my needs and it removes the `'You must use this format:'` message. Thanks and +1

Answer (score 4):

I like to use like this:

```
<input type="email" name="Email" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('ErrorMessage')"/>
```

And unplugged for all of valid input data

**UPD**, one more thing for better work:

```
    $("input").attr("onblur", "setCustomValidity('')");
    $("input").attr("oninput", "setCustomValidity(' ')");
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest solution +1

Answer (score 1):

Although the answers for this question had good information, they weren't sufficient for my needs.  I need to display different messages depending on which validity rule failed.  In the other examples, the same validation failure message is used for all valiation failures.

The "validity" property of a form object holds the key to creating more than one validation failure message.

You can review all of the different "validity" property properties at this web site.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp

This example shows how to display two different validation messages.  If you uncomment the console.log() line below you can watch the validity property change as you type in a field.

```
<label for="user_password_new">New Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="user_password_new" id="user_password_new"
    pattern=".{6,}"
    value=""
    required
    oninput="
        setCustomValidity('');
        checkValidity();
        // console.log(validity);
        if (validity.patternMismatch) {
            setCustomValidity('Please enter at least six characters.');
        }
        else if (validity.valueMissing) {
            setCustomValidity('This field is required.');
        }
        else if (validity.valid) {
            setCustomValidity('');
        }
        // allow default validation message to appear for other validation failures
    "
>
```

NOTE: Some validity checks are "type" specific.  For example, the "rangeOverflow", "rangeUnderflow", and "stepMismatch" attributes get set if type uses them; type="number".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `title` as long as you don't mind having `'You must use this format:'` before your message. If you want a full custom message, the `setCustomValidity()` worked for me.