# setCustomValidity() is always shown even when form is filled correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, required

I have very simple form which i want to validate by using required attribute :

```
          <form name="form">
                <label for="Header">Overskrift</label>
                <input type="text" class="span5" name="Header" ng-model="Message.header" placeholder="Overskrift" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Indtast overskrift')"  required />

                <label for="Body">Tekst</label>
                <textarea name="Body" class="span5" ng-model="Message.body" rows="10" cols="20" placeholder="Besked" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Indtast Tekst')" required />
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send" ng-click="send()" />
            </form>
```

but doesnt matter how i fill out the form first field is always invalid and error message is shown, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should not use the self-closing syntax `<textarea ... />`, unless your page is intended to work only in XHTML mode, sent with an XML content type.

Comment: Regarding the basic problem, this is a duplicate, though the problem is incompletely described here. The point is that *after trying to submit data* with some error detected, the field has custom validity set, and this can only be changed by setting it to '', not by direct user actions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5: Why does my "oninvalid" attribute let the pattern fail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867407/html5-why-does-my-oninvalid-attribute-let-the-pattern-fail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the standard AngularJS form validation controls? Like:

```
<input type="text" class="span5" name="Header" ng-model="Message.header" placeholder="Overskrift" required />
```

And you could check the validity of your field as

```
$scope.form.Header.$dirty && $scope.form.Header.$invalid
```

where $dirty is an indicator if the field has been modified and $invalid indicates that the input field does not contain a valid value. See the [AngularJS docs on forms](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) for more info about it