# Is the html5 attribute pattern buggy?

Tags: html

The following input field is not working properly.

```
<input id="textinput" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Die Eingabe ist zu kurz')" pattern=".{5}" maxlength="255" required="" name="input[1164]" type="text" class="form-control input-md " value="">
```

**What is working?**

Typing in the right amount of characters and submitting.

**What is not working?**

e.g. typing in the wrong amount, hitting submit. After the expected error message is shown, I´m not able to reach the right amount of characters or to fill the input correct (in case it is not depending on the amount of characters).

**What browsers have I used to verfiy this bug?**

Chrome and Firefox, each in the last stable version.

**Want to see it live?**

http://jsfiddle.net/0efurqa9/

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5: Why does my "oninvalid" attribute let the pattern fail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867407/html5-why-does-my-oninvalid-attribute-let-the-pattern-fail)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer already exists :)

[HTML5: Why does my "oninvalid" attribute let the pattern fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867407/html5-why-does-my-oninvalid-attribute-let-the-pattern-fail)

If you set your field with `setcustomvalidity`, your field is invalid... And STAYS invalid. You need to force the behavior back to its original one, with `oninput="setCustomValidity('')"`, like this:

```
<form>
  <input id="textinput" 
    oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Die Eingabe ist zu kurz')" 
    oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required="required" pattern=".{5}" 
    maxlength="255" name="input[1164]" type="text" class="form-control input-md " 
    value="">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Also:

- I recommend the use of `required="required"` instead of `required=""`
- take care: this attribute is not supported in Internet Explorer 9, nor in Safari.

Comment: Personally I'd suggest `required` with no value - it's a boolean attribute, after all, so its mere presence is sufficient ;)