# Google Chrome pattern regex not working when dynamically creating form with setCustomValidity

Tags: javascript

It seems dynamically adding customValidity is breaking the pattern validation. Is there any way to fix this issue using Javascript?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Append validation issue</title>
<script>
function dothis(){
    var f = document.createElement("form");
    var i = document.createElement("input");
    i.type = "text";
    i.pattern = "[A-Z]{3}";
    i.setCustomValidity("watch me break");
    var s = document.createElement("input")
    s.type = "submit";
    f.appendChild(i);
    f.appendChild(s)
    document.getElementById("core").appendChild(f);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div onclick="dothis()">click</div>
<div id="core"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "It will not pass" is pretty vague.  What do you really see?

Comment: It will keep showing the Validity alert for username. the default action for not passing the regex. I also updated my issue.

Comment: can you show us the code that's creating the form? Odds are your issue lays somewhere in that.

Comment: guess I'll write something quick and see if the error reproduces. To try and show all the steps in creating the objects from this code is not that easy.

Comment: Can I get an example of a username you expect to pass but it doesn't?

Comment: added some code to give an idea of how the for element in question is being created. and I'm entering AAA for username.

Comment: @Jhecht I updated my answer with code that has recreated the issue.

Comment: Look at this question and its accepted answer, maybe it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16867407/2079781

Comment: I've modified your code and I think this should fix it: https://jsfiddle.net/oL07go4s/

Comment: @Rickkwa it does, if you want put it as the answer, I was heading for the same solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `setCustomValidity` will set the `customError` [property](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp) to true, and thus the element will always be invalid.

So we should use `setCustomValidity` when text is invalid, and clear when valid.

```
function dothis(){
    var f = document.createElement("form");
    var i = document.createElement("input");
    i.type = "text";
    i.pattern = "[A-Z]{3}";
    i.oninput = function() {
        this.setCustomValidity('');
    }
    i.oninvalid = function() {
        this.setCustomValidity("watch me break");
    }
    var s = document.createElement("input")
    s.type = "submit";
    f.appendChild(i);
    f.appendChild(s)
    document.getElementById("core").appendChild(f);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oL07go4s/

Comment: Why is nobody mentioning that we should clear `setCustomValidity` ? I've wasted so much time ... Thanks a lot mate.