# set custom validity on input always returns invalid

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to `setCustomValidity` on `input` elements to my local language.
This ends up `input.checkValidity()' or 'input.validity.valid` always be `false`

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#signup-form *').filter(':input:not([type=hidden])').each(function() {

        var $element = this;
        switch($element.id) {
            case 'email':
                $element.setCustomValidity('some msg1');
                break;
            case 'password':
                $element.setCustomValidity('some msg2');
                break;
            case 'confirmPassword':
                $element.setCustomValidity('some msg3');
                break;
            default:
                $element.setCustomValidity('some msg4');
                break;
        }
    });


    document.addEventListener('input', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var $input = e.target;
            if (!$.nodeName(input, 'input')) return;
            var $element = $(input).parent();
            var $_e = $element.context.id;
            if($input.checkValidity()) {
                $element.removeClass('invalid');
                $element.parent().removeClass('invalid');
            } else {
                $element.addClass('invalid');
                $element.parent().removeClass('invalid');
            }
    }, false);

}
```

**UPDATE**

Found this [OS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16878766/848677) to be useful as part of my question...

Comment: why are you mixing jquery with regular javascript?

Comment: @Alex, is that casuing the issue?

Comment: I dont know, its just not good coding at all. Either you use jQuery or you dont, dont mix it :)