# HTML5 event custom validation for required in PHP convert

Tags: php, wordpress, html, woocommerce

I need some help with required attribute on PHP version.
**Required field works fine**, but problem is with **oninvalid** **element** to show custom text like in HTML form.

**This is HTML version:**

```
<select required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Custom TXT!')">
```

**This is my PHP version of select drop-down box:**

```
$options               = $args['options'];
    $product               = $args['product'];
    $attribute             = $args['attribute'];
    $name                  = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );
    $id                    = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title( $attribute );
    $class                 = $args['class'];
    $show_option_none      = $args['show_option_none'] ? true : false;
    $show_option_none_text = $args['show_option_none'] ? $args['show_option_none'] : __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' ); // We'll do our best to hide the placeholder, but we'll need to show something when resetting options.

    if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {
        $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];
    }

    $html = '<select required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Custom TXT!')" id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '"' . '" data-show_option_none="' . ( $show_option_none ? 'yes' : 'no' ) . '">';
    $html .= '<option value="">' . esc_html( $show_option_none_text ) . '</option>';
```

Can someone help me with this line to make custom text show, now it gives only error. Thank you!

```
$html = '<select required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Custom TXT!')"
```

[http://prntscr.com/earmll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTIO2.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5: Why does my "oninvalid" attribute let the pattern fail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867407/html5-why-does-my-oninvalid-attribute-let-the-pattern-fail)

Comment: nope... I need in PHP code this element...

Comment: Well, you have to convert it to your PHP string

Comment: @LGSon maby some help? :))

Comment: If you know PHP syntax this should be simple .. I don't, I'm a .NET developer

Comment: You will have to escape the inner single quotation marks if that's exactly what you want in your code.

Comment: @Firearrow5235 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected... I tried this many times...

Comment: Check and make sure every single and double quotation mark has a match. In your editor you should be able to stick your cursor next to the mark and it's match will be highlighted. Syntax errors usually have nothing to do with the actual code, just the way it's written.

Comment: @Firearrow5235 but maby it is impossible  to use HTML event on php line?

Comment: I don't see why not. It's just a text string that PHP as adding to the HTML document before serving it to the user.

Comment: @Firearrow5235 nothing... Tried every possible move.. Maby someone else could help?

Answer (score 0):

Well... This is lesson for me to use normal IDE not np++...

```
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(\'Custom TXT!\')"
```

Closed.

Comment: Haha! I was certain those had to be escaped. Glad you finally figured it out. :)