# Different title when input invalid and input empty

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation, jsvalidation

I have an input:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]{0,20}" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please insert only letters')" required>
```

If I input a number, the title will appear. But if I don't input anything, it will give the same error title. How can the title when I input not only letters is different when I doesn't input anyhing?

Comment: Can you clarify your problem more?

Comment: Maybe it's because you also specified that input as `required`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is similar to the one in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867407/html5-why-does-my-oninvalid-attribute-let-the-pattern-fail).

The correct answer there says that:

> If you set a value with setCustomValidity() then the field is invalid. That is setting a non-zero length string causes the browser to consider the field invalid. In order to allow for the effects of any other validations you have to clear the custom validity:
>
> ```
>   <input type="password" name="user_password_new" pattern=".{6,}" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Minimum length is 6 characters')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
> ```

Here is a working example for your case to see:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]{0,20}" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please insert only letters')" required oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```