# HTML5 required Tag. How to make form valid again?

Tags: html, forms, validation

I am using the html5 attribute required to valid my input. I find once the form has become invalid, it doesn't recognize when the user has typed in valid information.

For example:

```
<input id="name" type="text" name="username" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a username!')">
```

If the user misses this feild it highlight red and tells the user to fill it in. If they then fill it in and click submit, it tells the user to fill it in.

How do I recover my forms once they have become invalid?

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043589/html5-oninvalid-doesnt-work-after-fixed-the-input-field ?

Comment: Thank you, I did search but couldn't find a relavent post :D

Answer (score 3):

It's not rechecking after declaring the form element invalid.  Try adding an empty setCustomValidity string to oninput. Ie:

```
<input id="name" type="text" name="username" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a username!')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar to @Julie answer but use onchange instead of oninput ...

I use `oninvalid` to set the custom validty error message and then use `onchange` to reset the message so the form can submit properly.

```
<input type="number" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter an INTEGER')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')" name="integer-only" value="0" min="0" step="1">
```