# Show custom HTML5 validation errors on load form

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Is there a way to show custom [HTML5 form validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh547102.aspx) errors on load form?

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to show custom error messages, or the HTML5 error messages?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361460/how-can-i-change-html-5-form-validation-errors-default-messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this one out:
http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-cva-setcustomvalidity

`object.setCustomValidity(error)`

sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/makque/DQvsH/

I have issues with the `type="email"` myself, since it still accepts input like **you@mail** as a valid email address, thanks for the question.

[edited]
I don't get it, but like this? http://jsfiddle.net/makque/wk4HY/

Comment: Mark, welcome to SO! This is that I need but ... is there a way to autoexecute `previewMessage()` on form load. I mean show messages at same time that form is loaded ( without click preview errors ).

Comment: Thanks, sorry about delay.