# Change the default HTML5 validation message language

Tags: html, validation

As the question says I'm trying to change the default language message that cames from the validation of an email field: `<input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" required />`, I'm trying to avoid the use of a custom RegEx via Javascript.. I've tryied to use the  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en">` directive but it keep on showing the validation message in my language (Italian) but I want it to be displayed in English.
Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12364405/956660

Comment: Try the following   <html lang="en">