# How to add form validation pattern in Angular 2?

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-forms

I have a simple form that needs to validate if the beginning and the end of the input is not space.

In HTML5, I will do this:

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^(?!\s|.*\s$).*$">
```

What is the right property for validation pattern in the new Angular 2 ngControl directive? The official Beta API is still lacking documentation on this issue.

Comment: Currently there's no straightforward way to do it. You can write your own custom validator until this [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/5561) lands, if it does at all.

Comment: Here is an example of how to do custom validation if you go down that path http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/forms-and-validation-in-angular-2.0

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Now, you don't need to use `FormBuilder` and all this complicated valiation angular stuff. I put more details from this (Angular 2.0.8 - 3march2016):
https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/38cb526

Example from repo :

```html
<input [ngControl]="fullName" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*">
```

I test it and it works :) - here is my code:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(room)" #roomForm='ngForm'  >
...
<input 
  id='room-capacity' 
  type="text" 
  class="form-control" 
  [(ngModel)]='room.capacity' 
  ngControl="capacity" 
  required
  pattern="[0-9]+" 
  #capacity='ngForm'>
```

### Alternative approach (UPDATE June 2017)

Validation is ONLY on server side. If something is wrong then server return error code e.g [HTTP 400](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#400) and following json object in response body (as example):

```js
this.err = { 
    "capacity" : "too_small"
    "filed_name" : "error_name", 
    "field2_name" : "other_error_name",
    ... 
}
```

In html template I use separate tag (div/span/small etc.)

```html
<input [(ngModel)]='room.capacity' ...>
<small *ngIf="err.capacity" ...>{{ translate(err.capacity) }}</small>
```

If in 'capacity' is error then  tag with msg translation will be visible. This approach have following advantages:

- it is very simple
- avoid backend validation code duplication on frontend (for regexp validation this can either prevent or complicate [ReDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS) attacks)
- control on way the error is shown (e.g. `<small>` tag)
- backend return **error_name** which is easy to translate to proper language in frontend

Of course sometimes I make exception if validation is needed on frontend side (e.g. `retypePassword` field on registration is never send to server).

Comment: I just check (and test) changelog mention by Chris Snowden in his previous answer. He give the main hint.

Comment: What is the formula to covert patterns to this new type?

e.g. :   ng-pattern="/^(\+\91{1,2})\d{10}$/"

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi I don't understand question, could you repeat it in other words ?

Comment: When i use regex string which works in angular 1.x as pattern, in Angular2, It won't work. Why?

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi remove '/' at the begining and ad the end your regexp. so it should be in your case: pattern="^(\+\91{1,2})\d{10}$" (may be you must also remove or change backslashes '\' in your regexp)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski, I'm still finding FormBuilder in Many Examples and Documents. can you help me with any document without FormBuilder please?

Comment: why without FormBuilder? You don't need to use form builder. You can add validation after type each character  (you do it by input attributte (change)="validate($event)" )  and in validate function in Typescript check regexp and show hide some error message in you template

Comment: Using this method, how do you set the error message?

Comment: @zennin You can try this (but I don't check it) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361460/how-can-i-change-or-remove-html5-form-validation-default-error-messages

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52091334/password-validation-is-not-working-in-angular-5 @KamilKiełczewski

Answer (score 11):

Since version 2.0.0-beta.8 (2016-03-02), Angular now includes a [`Validators.pattern`](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern) regex validator.

See the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2830df4190e98d05bad396993776d31ba6efa6e2/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Great answer - you save may day ! :)

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52091334/password-validation-is-not-working-in-angular-5 @ChrisSnowden

Answer (score 9):

You could build your form using FormBuilder as it let you more flexible way to configure form.

```
export class MyComp {
  form: ControlGroup;

  constructor(@Inject()fb: FormBuilder) {  
    this.form = fb.group({  
      foo: ['', MyValidators.regex(/^(?!\s|.*\s$).*$/)]  
    });  
  }
```

Then in your template :

```
<input type="text" ngControl="foo" />
<div *ngIf="!form.foo.valid">Please correct foo entry !</div>
```

You can also customize ng-invalid CSS class.

As there is actually no validators for regex, you have to write your own. It is a simple function that takes a control in input, and return null if valid or a StringMap if invalid.

```
export class MyValidators {
  static regex(pattern: string): Function {
    return (control: Control): {[key: string]: any} => {
      return control.value.match(pattern) ? null : {pattern: true};
    };
  }
}
```

Hope that it help you.

Comment: Angular2 has own pattern validator.

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/Validators-class.html

Comment: Exact. But it was not the case when the response was writtren, a year ago.

Answer (score 5):

***custom validation step by step***

Html template

```
  <form [ngFormModel]="demoForm">
  <input  
  name="NotAllowSpecialCharacters"    
  type="text"                      
  #demo="ngForm"
  [ngFormControl] ="demoForm.controls['spec']"
  >

 <div class='error' *ngIf="demo.control.touched">
   <div *ngIf="demo.control.hasError('required')"> field  is required.</div>
   <div *ngIf="demo.control.hasError('invalidChar')">Special Characters are not Allowed</div>
 </div>
  </form>
```

Component App.ts

```
import {Control, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, NgForm, NgClass} from 'angular2/common';
import {CustomValidator} from '../../yourServices/validatorService';
```

under class 
define

```
 demoForm: ControlGroup;
constructor( @Inject(FormBuilder) private Fb: FormBuilder ) {
    this.demoForm = Fb.group({
       spec: new Control('', Validators.compose([Validators.required,   CustomValidator.specialCharValidator])),
      })
}
```

under {**../../yourServices/validatorService.ts**}

```
export class CustomValidator {
    static specialCharValidator(control: Control): { [key: string]: any } {
   if (control.value) {
       if (!control.value.match(/[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";#@'<>?,.\/]/)) {            
           return null;
       }
       else {            
           return { 'invalidChar': true };
       }
   }

 }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution with Angular 4.0.1: Just showing the UI for required CVC input - where the CVC must be exactly 3 digits:

```
    <form #paymentCardForm="ngForm">         
...
        <md-input-container align="start">
            <input #cvc2="ngModel" mdInput type="text" id="cvc2" name="cvc2" minlength="3" maxlength="3" placeholder="CVC" [(ngModel)]="paymentCard.cvc2" [disabled]="isBusy" pattern="\d{3}" required />
            <md-hint *ngIf="cvc2.errors && (cvc2.touched || submitted)" class="validation-result">
                <span [hidden]="!cvc2.errors.required && cvc2.dirty">
                    CVC is required.
                </span>
                <span [hidden]="!cvc2.errors.minlength && !cvc2.errors.maxlength && !cvc2.errors.pattern">
                    CVC must be 3 numbers.
                </span>
            </md-hint>
        </md-input-container>
...
<button type="submit" md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="confirm($event, paymentCardForm.value)" [disabled]="isBusy || !paymentCardForm.valid">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without make validation patterns, You can easily trim begin and end spaces using these modules.Try this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-trim-directive
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-trim-directive

Thank you.

Comment: Actually, for both, trim="blur" will do the trick if space is allowed inside (middle of) the value.