# Validation pattern for date in DD/MM/YYYY format using angular2

Tags: angular

How to add validation pattern for Date in DD/MM/YYYY format using angular2 Validator.pattern.

I have the "required" validator in place. Cannot find one for date pattern. Code as below:

```
this.txtDob = new Control("", Validators.compose([Validators.required]));
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in date validator. You have to create a custom one http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html

Your validator will look like this https://github.com/Angular2Buch/angular2-forms/blob/master/src/app/validators/date.validator.ts

**Update**:
You need to have class for the validator. Specify it as a second element of array in `Validators.compose`:

```
Validators.compose([Validators.required, MyValidator])
```

Pattern may work too: [How to add form validation pattern in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559212/how-to-add-form-validation-pattern-in-angular2)

Comment: Will adding this "/^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}$/"  in Validators.pattern work?
Like :

Validators.pattern('/^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}$/')

Answer (score 3):

You can create a simple custom validator as below

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {FormControl} from "@angular/forms";


@Injectable()
export class DateValidator {

  constructor() {
  }

  static date(c: FormControl) {
    const dateRegEx = new RegExp(/^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}$/);
    return dateRegEx.test(c.value) ? null : {date: true}
  }
}
```

and call it in your form

```
senddate: new FormControl(new Date(), Validators.compose([Validators.required, DateValidator.date])),
```

And then simply show the error in your html

```
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls.senddate.dirty && form.controls.senddate.errors?.date">
        La date d'envoi n'est pas <strong>valide</strong>
      </mat-error>
```

I hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a service( not mandatory, i.e the following could easily be changed to a regular function ) as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

    interface Validator<T extends FormControl> {
      (c: T): { [error: string]: any };
    }

    @Injectable()
    export class DateValidatorClass {

      constructor() { }
      dateValidator(c: FormControl) {

        const dateRegEx = new RegExp(yourRegExInHere);;

        return c.value.test(dateRegEx) ? null : {
          dateValidator: {
            valid: false
          }
    };
  }
}
```