# input validation angular2localization

Tags: validation, angular, localization

I find an example for number validation in the angular2localization API . Can I also validate percentage, currency or date input fields with this API or is there something planed to do that? Or does another API exists in order to validate swiss german date and currency inputs in angular 2?

Answer (score 0):

with the validation of the numbers, you can also manage the currency.

I was planning to implement the validation of dates, but there are two open questions:

- An algorithm is needed for each calendar
- Normally it used a datepicker with its own style

If you need to validate a date in only one language, you can implement a custom validator: [Validation pattern for date in DD/MM/YYYY format using angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859790/validation-pattern-for-date-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-using-angular2)

Try to see also this library: https://github.com/yuyang041060120/ng2-validation

Greetings