# Check date is correct + regex Angular4

Tags: html, angular

I have a form in Angular4, with 2 dates: started, finished.

I want to check that the format date is dd/mm/yyyy.

I wrote:

```
     <input  pattern="((0)*[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)*[1-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)\d{4}$" [(ngModel)]="filterDateStart" class="form-control" type="date" id="filterDateStart" name="filterDateStart"  clrDate>

    <input   pattern="((0)*[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)*[1-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)\d{4}$" [(ngModel)]="filterDateEnd" class="form-control" type="date" id="filterDateEnd" name="filterDateEnd"  clrDate>
```

Then when I write invalid dates , my html doesn't say anything... I can send this form.

[image]

Then I need to check these dates.

```
 1º Date start < date end
 2º Ranges valid -> (30/20/2018) or (32/12/2018)
```

I see the library moment.js, but my boss says that I don't should be it. thanks, sorry for my english.

Comment: Since you are using angular 4 apparently, i'd rather reccomend using Validators in the form. Use a pattern validator to check for your format, and others for range, etc.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859790/validation-pattern-for-date-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-using-angular2/37860088#37860088

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regexes, rely on the `Date` API :

```js
const valid = '12/12/2018';
const invalid1 = '12/12';
const invalid2 = '12.12.2018';
const invalid3 = 'foo';

function parseDate(date) {
  try {
    // Make your business logic here. Examples : all must be defined and numbers, and separated with a /
    const [d, m, y] = date.split('/');
    
    if (!d || !m || !y) throw new Error();
    
    if(isNaN(d) || isNaN(m) || isNaN(y)) throw new Error();
    
    return new Date(y, m, d);
  } catch(err) {
    return 'Invalid date';
  }
}

console.log(parseDate(valid));
console.log(parseDate(invalid1));
console.log(parseDate(invalid2));
console.log(parseDate(invalid3));
```

With that you can create a custom validator, that will be a lot more explicit than using a pattern.

Comment: new Date(y, m, d) --->>> 30/02/2008, should be error --but not --> Sun Mar 30 2008 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central)

Comment: it's  working with my code because I only put two conditions in it. I'm giving a direction to follow, I'm not a code monkey.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52970849/i-can-created-date-30-02-yyyy-with-typescript?noredirect=1#comment92850824_52970849. Sorry