# Working on Angular 2 form validation. How to prevent the user entering the special character in to the input text box?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Angular 2 form Validation

scenario:

If user try to enter the special character in to the input type="text", it should be prevented from being entered ?

special characters should not appear in to the corresponding text box ?

Comment: Please refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559212/how-to-add-form-validation-pattern-in-angular2

Comment: @Sanket, validation pattern changes dynamically,  but my behaviour of input control should not allow the user to enter the pattern mentioned for that control

Comment: This approach might work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800841/input-mask-fields-in-angular2-forms

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  the above approach works good. Now i face problem with caret position with the validation mask. when i type some string to the input [type ="text"]. with that validation mask directive i try to replace the input string with matched pattern. scenario: when i try to edit from middle of the string ( placing the caret position between the string ) entered in input [type ="text"], the caret position shift to last. it doesn't allow to change in middle of the string.

Comment: Sorry, don't know about that. Maybe someone else. A Plunker to reproduce might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

**code, which shown below fix the caret position problem**
 1. changing the event type to '(input)' inside the  host listener.
 2. inside the class define the start and end position of the caret, it solves the problem

```
@Directive({
selector: '[ngModel][maskSpecialCharacter]',
host: {
    '(ngModelChange)': 'onInputChange($event)',
    '(input)': 'onInputChange($event.target.value, true)'
 }
})
      export class SpecialCharacterMask {
         constructor(public model: NgControl, public ele: ElementRef, public render: Renderer) { }

onInputChange(event, backspace) {
    var position = this.ele.nativeElement.selectionStart;
    var value = event.replace(/[!$%^&*()+|~=`{}\[\]:";#@'<>?,.\/\\]/gi, '');
    this.render.setElementProperty(this.ele.nativeElement, "value", value);
    this.ele.nativeElement.selectionEnd = position;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validator,

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms'

export function restrictedWords(words) {
    return (control: FormControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
        if (!words) return null
        var invalidWords = words.map(w => control.value.includes(w) ? w : null)
            .filter(w => w != null)
        return invalidWords && invalidWords.length > 0
            ? { 'restrictedWords': invalidWords.join(', ') }
            : null
    }
}
```

Call the custom validator function from your form,

```
this.textBox1 = new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(400), restrictedWords(['foo','bar'])])
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach for Angular Reactive Form:

Need to add a Validator in form Validation.
Also, below regex will not work with internationalization. Please change the regex as per need.

```
    this.form= this.formBuilder.group({
        name: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()]+$/)] ],
        description: ['']
    });
```

Please note you don't need quotes for Validators.pattern method

**Approach 2**

```
export function isSecuredInput(input: string): boolean {
    const tagBody = '(?:[^"\'>]|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*';
    const tagOrComment = new RegExp(
        '<(?:'
        // Comment body.
        + '!--(?:(?:-*[^->])*--+|-?)'
        // Special "raw text" elements whose content should be elided.
        + '|script\\b' + tagBody + '>[\\s\\S]*?</script\\s*'
        + '|style\\b' + tagBody + '>[\\s\\S]*?</style\\s*'
        // Regular name
        + '|/?[a-z]'
        + tagBody
        + ')>',
        'gi');

    return input.search(tagOrComment) === -1 ? true : false;
}
```

Changes in Form:

```
isValidInput(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
        if (!isNullOrUndefined(control.value)) {
            return isSecuredInput(control.value.toString()) ? null : { invalid: true};
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

and Form would be

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        name:  new FormControl('', {
            validators: [Validators.required, this.isValidInput()],
            updateOn: 'change'
        })
})
```

Source isSecure is from [Sanitize/Rewrite HTML on the Client Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295566/sanitize-rewrite-html-on-the-client-side)

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Pattern as

```
 this.form= this.fb.group({
        name: ['', [Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9 ]')]],
 });
```