# Bootstrap 4 Built-in validator - Error text

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation, twitter-bootstrap-4

I made a simple form using Bootstrap 4. I thought the built-in validator in BS4 could be usefull.

I made an simple email form field:

```
<label for="email">E-mail cím:</label><br>
<input type="email" name="email" class="inputText"><br>
```

My problem is that, when I type a false adress, It comes back with english text. But I want to make a hungarian site.

Do you have any idea where can I change this text? I Googled It for an hour and haven't found anything.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjYgV.png)

Thanks
Gergo

Comment: not's Bootstrap 4 is the Google Chrome who show this message, and you can validate your input, and personalize with jQuery

Comment: How can I customize the text? What is the name of this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [How can I change or remove HTML5 form validation default error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361460/how-can-i-change-or-remove-html5-form-validation-default-error-messages).

To set a custom message to your validator error input, use something like

```
 <input type="email"
    oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Invalid email!')"
    onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" />
```

---

There is also a change you did not set the locale (language) of the page.

Do this by adding the `lang` attribute to your `<html>` tag, like:

```
<html lang="hu">
  ...
</html>
```