# How to disable auto-validation for IE10 in HTML 5?

Tags: angularjs, html

I added `max-length` and I am getting this [**message**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZNMn.png) in IE (Internet Explorer) but I didn't need that message it should only validate. I tried no-validate but it removes validation. I only want to remove this message from IE and it should validate. And on other browsers its working fine.

Any Help?

Comment: Please provide use your code and what you've already tried

Comment: Did you already try this: [How can I change or remove HTML5 form validation default error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361460/how-can-i-change-or-remove-html5-form-validation-default-error-messages)

Comment: <input type="text" maxlength="1">

Comment: Edit your code and post proper example

Comment: I only need to remove that message box i.e. "You must enter text with 1 or fewer characters" only facing this issue on IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code :

```
$('input').on("invalid", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

It will prevent default behavior on `invalid` input for all input tag

**OR**

```
<input id="textBox1" type="text" maxlength="4" oninvalid="setCustomValidity(' ')">
```

Above code will set your validation message to blank.