# Safari HTML validation doesn't display input title when used with a pattern attribute

Tags: html, validation, input, safari, safari-11

I'm using HTML form validation to check the user's input for various fields, like this simple ZIP code field:

```
<input id="zip" type="text" pattern="[0-9]{5}" title="e.g., 12345" required />
```

In basically all supporting browsers - Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Edge, even IE11 - if the user's input doesn't match the `pattern`, the text of the `title` attribute is displayed as a hint. In Chrome, for example, the following message is displayed:

> Please match the requested format: e.g., 12345

But Safari merely says:

> Match the requested format

...while ignoring the `title` attribute, so it doesn't actually *say* what the requested format is.

Is there any way to get Safari to display the `title` attribute, or some alternative way I can have it display a hint indicating what the requested format is?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a fix but a work-around for this issue I found was by using the `oninvalid` attribute, thanks to this reply I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/12364405

I also realised that Safari does show the title tooltip but only if you hover over the input field rather than displaying it with the validation message.
Hope this answer helps.