# How can I change HTML5 form validation default error messages for min and max?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I found this answer for changing error message for invalid values [How can I change or remove HTML5 form validation default error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361460/how-can-i-change-or-remove-html5-form-validation-default-error-messages).

I need to show different message for value less than min and more than max.

```
<input type="number" name="test" step="any" min="0.01" max="10.0">
```

If user enters -1, it should say "Please enter positive value".

If user enters 20, it should say "Value cannot be more than 10".

Comment: what's wrong with the answer you linked? Just make general message `oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Enter a number beween 0.01 and 10 ')"`

Comment: The actual use case is complex like, "you cannot enter more than 10 because your limit is expired".

Answer (score 0):

There may be some fancy API-driven way to do it, but if the `title` is displayed when the input doesn't match a `pattern`, you can just modify the the `title` on change.

To support decimals, you'll need some fancier regex.

*I included the `form` tag so the validation would work in the snippet

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if (e.target.value > 10) {
    e.target.setAttribute('title', "Value cannot be more than 10");
  } else if (e.target.value < 0) {
    e.target.setAttribute('title', "Please enter a positive value");
  } else {
    e.target.setAttribute('title', "Please enter a number");
  }
})
```

```html
<form><input type="text" required="" pattern="10|[0-9]" value="" title="This is an error message" /></form>
```

Comment: I think `^10$|^([0-9](\.[0-9]{1,})?)$` should work to support decimals, but I'm not confident.

Answer (score 0):

With the HTML5 form validation (from your link) you can use a custom message by using the `invalid` event listener on the `input` element.

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");
myInput.addEventListener("invalid", validate);
myInput.addEventListener("keyup", validate);

function validate() {
  var val = parseFloat(this.value);
  var min = parseFloat(this.min);
  var max = parseFloat(this.max);
  
  if (val < min) {
    this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a positive number');
  } else if (val > max) {
    this.setCustomValidity('Value cannot be more than ' + max);
  } else {
    this.setCustomValidity("");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="myInput" type="number" name="test" step="any" min="0.01" max="10.0">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```